# RSS error in ASP.NET web-site

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss, webforms

Tryed to search in google, but have not found anything useful to solve this problem, so here we are.
Have a page, where using RSS should alert 10 last news from DB. Have done this task using this lesson  - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-build-an-rss-feed-with-asp-net/ 
Seems like I did everything right, but when i start my application - I have a next error, or alert, nvm:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The     document tree is shown below.
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Name of the website</title>
<link>http://pudel.com</link>
<description>Short description of the site</description>
<item>
<title>Jenzyk Polski</title>
<link>http://localhost:56957/rss.aspx?ID=11</link>
<pubDate>Wed, 03 Apr 2013 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<description>Co to jest?</description>
</item>
<item>
<title>Czy mowic pana zona po Polsku?</title>
<link>http://localhost:56957/rss.aspx?ID=13</link>
<pubDate>Tue, 02 Apr 2013 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<description>Tak, bardzo dobze mowic</description>
</item>
<item>
<title>Kim jestes z pochodzenia?</title>
<link>http://localhost:56957/rss.aspx?ID=12</link>
<pubDate>Tue, 02 Apr 2013 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<description>Jestes Polakiem</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
[/XML]
```

Surely, this view is not what I have planed to do. So, where is the problem? Tryed to open with different browsers-all the same. Tryed to change encoding in web.config from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1251 - all the same.

Here is the code for rss.aspx.cs page:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace softacom.pb
{
public partial class rss : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = connString;

        string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 newsID, Title, Date, Description FROM News ORDER BY Date DESC";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

        sqlConn.Open();
        RepeaterRSS.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        RepeaterRSS.DataBind();
        sqlConn.Close();

    }
    protected string RemoveIllegalCharacters(object input)
    {
        string data = input.ToString();
        data = data.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        data = data.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
        data = data.Replace("'", "&apos;");
        data = data.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        data = data.Replace(">", "&gt;");

        return data;
    }


}
 }
```

And here is rss.ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/xml"  AutoEventWireup="true"     CodeBehind="rss.aspx.cs" Inherits="softacom.pb.rss" %>

 <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterRSS" runat="server">
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
 <title>Name of the website</title>
 <link>http://pudel.com</link>
 <description> Short description of the site</description>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <item>
 <title><%# RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title"))%>   </title>
 <link>http://localhost:56957/rss.aspx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "newsID") %></link>
 <pubDate><%# String.Format("{0:R}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date"))%>  </pubDate>  
 <description><%# RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description"))%></description>  
    </item>  
    </ItemTemplate>  
    <FooterTemplate>  
            </channel>  
        </rss>    
    </FooterTemplate>  
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: _"I have a next error, or alert, nvm: [...] Surely, this view is not what I have planed to do."_ - please explain the problem better, show what the expected and actual results are.

Comment: Ok, expect to see the page like this: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/842_rssFeed/images/rss.jpg   But see only the first code that is shown in this topic: his XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The     document tree is shown below.

Comment: Btw, tryed to open it in Firefox - it shows it correct. but Chrome showing this problem, and IE shows nothing:)

Comment: The problem was solved by adding RSS plugin to Chrome. Thanks a lot!